# How to solve NULL pointer error when using Jackson 1.x

Tags: java, serialization, jackson

I use an API from where I request data. For one request I receive a NULL pointer exception when I try to set the value to an int.

```
public class Player implements Serializable  {
...
...
...
...
   @JsonProperty("offsides")
    private Integer offsides;
...
...

    @JsonProperty("offsides")
    public Integer getOffsides() {
        return offsides;
    }

    @JsonProperty("offsides")
    public void setOffsides(Integer offsides) {
        this.offsides = offsides;
    }
```

...

```
public class Fixtures {
private final static long serialVersionUID = 2571183788260356219L;
        public static void main(String args[]) throws Exception  {

            ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
            ...
            ...
            ...
            FixtureJSONMapp fixturesFixtures = mapper.readValue(fixturesFile, FixtureJSONMapp.class);

           List<String> insertStatus = FixturesFixturesInsert.insertAllFixtures(fixturesFixtures, 
           statsNumb, playersNumb, eventsNumb, lineupsNumb);
        }
}
```

...

```
public class FixturesFixturesInsert {
    
    public static List<String> insertAllFixtures(FixtureJSONMapp fixturesFixtures, int statsNumb, int playersNumb, int eventsNumb, int lineupsNumb) throws Exception    {
            try {
            
            Connection con = dbConnector.ConnectToDB();
            PreparedStatement pstmtFixtures = con.prepareStatement(".....");

            for(int i = 0; i < fixturesFixtures.getApi().getFixtures().size(); i++) {

            ...
            ...
            ...
            ...
            int offsides = fixturesFixtures.getApi().getFixtures().get(i).getPlayers().get(j).getOffsides();
            ...
            }
   }
```

It is for the "int offsides" I get an NULL pointer exception in this case. I can solve by
int offsides = (fixtures....getOffsides() != null ? getOffsides() : 0);
But I thought I should be able to use mapper.getSerializationConfig().setSerializationInclusion(Inclusion.NON_NULL); or something similar but I can´t get it to work. I would like to set this setting more global because I will have to do it in many places.

I would like to set value to 0 if it is NULL in the JSON String i receive. Is this possible to do?
As mentioned in the subject I use Jackson 1.x (org.codehaus.jackson)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of make sure that `setSerializationInclusion(...)` is applied on an incoming data. I don't think so, it takes effect for data you are about to send.

NOTE:

1. Even if it works, you are trying to access `null` and assign it to a primitive.
2. `NullPointerException` tells that you are calling `getOffsides()` on a `null` object. i.e. `null.getOffsides()`
3. If you are using atleast Java 8, you can use `Optional.ofNullable` to set `int offsides` to `0` whenever it is `null`